# How to user iron-fit-behavior to center an form inside a custom element in polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm new into Polymer and I'm still having some doubts about how to use some elements properly. In this case, I having difficulties on centering a custom element inside other.

I have the element app-main-search which should be basically a image with a form centered:

```
<dom-module id="app-main-search">
<template>
<style>
    :host {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }
    .app-main-search-img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>

    <iron-image class="app-main-search-img" id="main-search-img" sizing="cover" src="../../images/slider-image1.jpg"></iron-image>
    <app-main-search-form fit-into="#main-search-img" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"></app-main-search-form>

    </template>
    <script>
    (function() {
    'use strict';
    Polymer({
        is: 'app-main-search',
        properties: {
        }
    });
    })();
    </script>
    </dom-module>
```

The element app-main-search has the following code:

```
    <dom-module id="app-main-search-form">
<template>

<style>
:host {
    @apply(--layout);
    text-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;
}
</style>

<div class="container flex-vertical">
    <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/form/handler">
        <paper-dropdown-menu class="featured-events-others">
            <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
            <paper-item selected>Item1</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Item2</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Item3</paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        <paper-input name="label1"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="label1"></paper-input>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
(function() {
'use strict';

Polymer({
    is: 'app-main-search-form',

behaviors: [
    Polymer.IronFitBehavior
]
});
})();
</script>
</dom-module>
```

If I use the "autoFitOnAttach", it gets centered on window, but none of the combinations that I tried using "fit-into" worked. Can someone help me using this behavior properly? I didn't find any example of this element besides the official Polymer code and it doesn't have a example using "fit-into"

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fitInto property expects a DOM element object, but your code is only assigning a string to it. You can do something like this to get the element object:

```
<app-main-search-form fit-into="[[getElement('#main-search-img')]]" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"></app-main-search-form>
```

Then in your element's js:

```
getElement: function(elStr) {
  return this.querySelector(elStr)
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this with an actual iron-fit-behavior example, but this definitely solves the element object issue.

Comment: Thank you very much sfeast. I adjusted fit-into to pass an element instead of a string and after some CSS adjustes is working perfectly.

While I was stuck in this problem I was using a regular div with a background-image. But, a iron-image has much more features that will help me create a better designed application.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked out! Mind accepting this is as the answer?